# How to Block this Ad with AdBlock on Google Chrome Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, adblock

When I go to this page, http://www.hkej.com/template/landing11/jsp/main.jsp, I get an ad which is like a "light box" and the rest of the page becomes greyed out.  In case you cannot reproduce it, I have attached a screenshot.[image: screenshot]

I cannot block this ad with AdBlock, the best that I can do is get rid of the contents of this "pop up" but not remove it completely.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am a paying subscriber to that website, so it's extra annoying that I stil suffer these intrusive ads.

Comment: It's not a technical solution, but you could try emailing the site admins and telling them that you don't appreciate being sent popup ads as a paying customer, and they'll lose your business if they continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the XJZ Survey Remover, it works perfectly! im sure it will work for this website ( i hope you your sake it does!) http://survey-remover.com/

--EDIT: i have confirmed it works on the provided webpage, just make sure you make the script XJZ provides into a bookmark so you can easily click it in the bookmarking bar, then make sure you click try the beta thing and delete the total outside of the box that is blocking the information you are trying to get to and then click again to get rid of the grey out part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this chrome extension [JavaScript Popup Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-popup-blocker/hiajdlfgbgnnjakkbnpdhmhfhklkbiol/details?hl=en) free available on chrome web store. I also tried and working for me.